Is automatic scraping forbidden on EURLEX?
Is it possible that the EU has removed the possibility to scrape the EURLEX Website?
For a university course I am required to scrape the following website for all the listed documents in an html format that we then further process. I have implemented a simple webscraper in Beautifulsoup that does that job. This one has worked before, but some weeks ago it stopped.
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')

However here: I always get the following error:

Your request has been blocked due to new security measures.
Please contact us to discuss alternative solutions.
You can also consult EUR-lex help on <a href="https://eur-lex.europa.eu/content/help/data-reuse/reuse-contents-eurlex-details.html"

I first thought that they have only moved it behind a login wall, which I try to work around by trying different things from another post:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import http.cookiejar as cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open(login_url)

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = data['username']
br.form['password'] = data['password']
br.submit()

print(br.response().read()) 

However here, I get the following error:

HTTP Error 403: b'request disallowed by robots.txt'

Some googling tells me that this prohibits automated login attempts on this website.
Is there a way to still scrape these documents?
Would really appreciate any help here. Thanks guys

When I used a browser to look at the site in your link it has this message: Your request has been blocked due to new security measures. Please contact us to discuss alternative solutions. You can also consult EUR-lex help on data reuse.  It is probably worth reporting this to the university tutor, as I am sure that they would not like to be seen encouraging students to try to defeat website security systems.
